# Can I check if there is a user in the voice channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Turning the translator around can make English seem unnatural.

If there are no users on the voice channel, the program will fail.

So I would like to check if there are users on the voice channel and know the function of discord.py which does the bool or other reset type.

```
elif message.content.startswith('>보이스'):

    tmp = str(message.author.display_name).split()
    tmp = tmp[2].split('(')


    if(len(tlst) >= 10 ):
        for i in range(0,len(lst)):
            if(tlst[4] == 3):
                print(i)
                vnum = tlst[i]
                vch = 'Duo_'+ str(vnum)
                print(vch)
                if(tmp[0] == lst[i]) == True:
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="이동완료!", color=0x00ff00)
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
                    channel = discord.utils.find(lambda x: x.name == vch, message.server.channels)
                    await client.move_member(message.author , channel)

            elif(tlst[4] == 2):
                vnum = tlst[i]
                vch = 'Squad_'+ str(vnum)
                if(tmp[0] == lst[i]) == True:
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="이동완료!", color=0x00ff00)
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
                    channel = discord.utils.find(lambda x: x.name == vch, message.server.channels)
                    await client.move_member(message.author , channel)
            else:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="띠용", description="팀 5는 보이스 기능이 없습니다.", color=0x00ff00)
                await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="띠용", description="팀을 먼저 짜주세요~", color=0x00ff00)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. To improve your chances of getting an answer i suggest that you take a look at [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help you get the help you seek much faster.

Comment: sorry and thank u . im add my code . coud you check it?

Comment: The answer of Patrick Haugh is not right anymore. It is now Channel.members instead of voice_members

Comment: The answer of Patrick Haugh is not right anymore. It is now Channel.members instead of voice_members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of [`Channel.voice_members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Channel.voice_members), which will be a list of members in the channel.